# What does "get the effect of" mean?

Tags: meaning

I quoted this paragraph from internet which is about what is MVC(the pattern of Model-View-Controller).

> I don't find it terribly useful to think of MVC as a pattern because
>   it contains quite a few different ideas. Different people reading
>   about MVC in different places take different ideas from it and
>   describe these as 'MVC'. If this doesn't cause enough confusion you
>   then get the effect of misunderstandings of MVC that develop through a
>   system of Chinese whispers.

I just can't figure out what is the last sentence meaning . I know the game of Chinese whispers. What is the author trying to express? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from this text is that there is an initial grade of confusion regarding MVC, generated by the fact that there are different ideas in relation to MVC and that are expressed differently depending on the source (as a result, different people reading about MVC from different sources get different ideas regarding MVC).

In addition to that, there is a second grade of confusion that generates when those people (who may already have formed different ideas of MVC and may not have grasped the concept properly) explain their own idea of MVC to others, and this idea deteriorates gradually (as happens with the game of Chinese whispers).

So I would say that the phrase "If this doesn't cause enough confusion you then get the effect of misunderstandings of MVC that develop through a system of Chinese whispers" means that in addition to the initial confusion generated by having different ideas regarding MVC, you get the effects of the degradation of those ideas when they are propagated further by people who might not have fully grasped them.